# AngularJS: Maintain list of progress bars dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm an AngularJS beginner, and am trying to build upon a small Rails app that performs some operations in a collection of threads. Depending on user actions, there can be any amount of simultaneous threads running at once.

The app uses AngularJS and Bootstrap elsewhere, and seems like a good set of libraries for implementing progress bars to keep track of the progress of each active thread. However, I'm not entirely sure how to maintain these progress bars: updating them as each thread progresses, and how to add and remove them from my page as threads are created and terminated. I've poked around in the AngularJS and Bootstrap API pages, but I'm honestly not a very strong web developer, so JS isn't really my strong suit.

Would anyone be able to point me into the right direction to learn how to accomplish these actions? Thank you!

[EDIT] I thought it would be helpful to post a portion of my code that attempts to at least load these progress bars on page load. The following is from the page's `.html.erb` file:

```
<div id="active_threads">
        <%= $active_threads.each do | active_thread | %>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%= active_thread.progress %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
                    <span class="sr-only"><%= active_thread.to_s %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

here, `$active_threads` is an Array maintained in another .rb file, which includes, as it implies, a list of all of the active threads. These threads are added to the array when created, and removed from it just before they terminate. This code doesn't work; no progress bars load, and I can verify there are entries in `$active_threads`. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: are you sure you should be using `<%=..>` and not `<%..%>` in your second line: `<%= $active_threads.each do | active_thread | %>`?     -     seems to me you want the inner block to display and not the result of the inner block (which is nothing)... but I use [Slim](http://slim-lang.com), and I'm not sure about erb anymore...

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of patterns to do this, such as websockets, server-sent events, forever frames and long polling.  Websockets is the most modern solution, but may not be supported by older browsers or servers.

Most websocket frameworks will try to use websockets, then automatically fall back to one of the other options if websockets are not supported.  I don't use ruby so I'm not familiar with the most used websocket frameworks there - possibly https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails ?

edit:  With the code you posted, once that code is run on the server and sent to the client, it cannot be changed.  It's gone.  What all of the solutions above do is send further requests to the server once the page has been rendered by the client, so that the server can tell the page when to make updates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that my code sample above is a one-shot; I had written it just to test a method to load the progress bars for each thread. However, like I said, no progress bars are drawn, even though I'm sure there are active threads present in the Array. Is the page unaware of the contents of this array, even at page load?

Comment: I think it should be able to see the array when the view is being rendered (again, I've never written ruby) but I would say that threads are too unreliable to do what you're trying to do there: they can stop or complete at any time, including before or during rendering your view.

Comment: Yes, I realize it's not a real solution for what I'm actually attempting to accomplish; I'm just trying to do a shakedown to ensure the "progress" value kept in the Rails model can be used to set the percentage of a progress bar, and that's somewhere I'm running into an issue.